# Two Arrays: One validates what content will be displayed from the other - with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two Arrayes that has been sourced from two different URIs. I am trying to create a form of code that extracts specific data from one Array and connects it to related data from the other Array. Here's an example:

```
let coursesData = ['teachers': 'CHCH'];

let teacherData = [
{
'id': {'name': 'CHCH'},
'name':{ 
'jobtitle': 'Professor',
'firt':'Charie',
'last': Chaplin 
},
}];

function renderCourseTeachersList () {

  teacherData
    .filter(object => {
      return object.id.includes(parseInt(coursesData.teachers));
    })
    .forEach((item, i) => {
      console.log(`Lärare: ${item.name.jobtitle} ${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`);
  });
}
```

I was hoping this would give me a list of the values: jobtitle, first and last in the console log, in order of the matching value: CHCH.

The two arrays are just snippets of a larger source.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this an object or array? `['teachers': 'CHCH'];` ? `object.id` is not an array, so does not have the `includes` function.

Comment: shouldn't your var coursesData be an array of objects? therefore it should look like this `let coursesData = [{teachers: 'CHCH'}];` if is not an array of objects then your data is pretty messed up or contains syntax errors, also is that the only object stored in your coursesData var or it contains multiple objects?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your comments. My snippet from the actual array was something i just wrote, so sorry for any spelling mistakes. To answer the first question: I am working with an array, although this is not the entire one . What did you mean "object.id" is not an array? ... second comment, I have a .json file, converted to an array and no errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you put a snippet of your source data, I guess coursesData is an array of objects. So I defined multiple objects in coursesData. If your structure is different, Snippet will provide you idea to get the expected result.

```js
let coursesData = [ 
    {
        'teachers': 'CHCH'
    },
    {
        'teachers': 'xyz'
    },
];

let teacherData = [
    {
        'id': {
            'name': 'CHCH'
        },
        'name': { 
            'jobtitle': 'Professor',
            'first': 'Charie',
            'last': 'Chaplin',
        },
    },
    {
        'id': {
            'name': 'xyz'
        },
        'name': { 
            'jobtitle': 'Lecturer',
            'first': 'John',
            'last': 'Doe',
        },
    }
];

function renderCourseTeachersList (){
    teacherData.filter(object => coursesData.some(subItem => subItem.teachers == object.id.name))
    .forEach((item, i) => {
        console.log(`Lärare: ${item.name.jobtitle} ${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`);
    });
}

renderCourseTeachersList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).